# how to migrate local datastore in google appengine python SDK 1.8.1

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using GAE python-SDK 1.7.1 and have to update to 1.8.1 and migrate the local datastore to HRD. The appserver is also running locally.
So far, all information i found is a procedure if you are using appspot "online-hosting".

I just could not figure out how to migrate the local datastore.
As i read, one should enable datastore_admin in order to get the button to migrate the datastore in admin interface of the appserver.

How do i enable this?
I found a subdir "google_appengine_SDK_python_1.8.1/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/".
But I don't know how to make it available in the default admin website at "http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin".

Is there an easier way to do the migration?
Maybe a commandline tool?

Comment: Do you mean to move your data in the local datastore to the appengine datastore, or do you mean you want to migrate your app from the old Master/Slave scheme to the new HRD?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to migrate the local datastore. That's just a file on disk. All the HRD logic is in the data access API in the SDK, and the dev server is already using that.